# How can you make python 2.x warn when coercing strings to unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

A very common source of encoding errors is that python 2 will silently coerce strings to `unicode` when you add them together with `unicode`. This can cause mixed encoding problems and can be very hard to debug.

For example:

```
import urllib
import webbrowser
name = raw_input("What's your name?\nName: ")
greeting = "Hello, %s" % name
if name == "John":
    greeting += u' (Feliz cumplea\xf1os!)'
webbrowser.open('http://lmgtf\x79.com?q=' + urllib.quote_plus(greeting))
```

will fail with a cryptic error if you enter "John":

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py:1268: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison faile
d to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "feliz.py", line 7, in <module>
    webbrowser.open('http://lmgtf\x79.com?q=' + urllib.quote_plus(greeting))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1273, in quote_plus
    s = quote(s, safe + ' ')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1268, in quote
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\xf1'
```

It's particularly hard to track down when the actual errors come far down the road from where the actual coercion happened.

How can you configure python to give a warning or exception immediately when strings are coerced to unicode?

Comment: Hrm... I had to mangle the "lmgtf y.com" URL because SO wouldn't let me post it otherwise...

Comment: AFAIK this isn't configurable, unfortunately.  [And I think that particular site was blocked because it was really only used as a snarky rickroll.  There are a few discussion on meta.]

Comment: Why are you not using `unicode` literals in the first place, and encoding them when it matters?

Comment: I think there's some confusion here.  From a recent answer, I think @MuMind knows how unicode works, and is asking if there was a way to get Python 3-style automatic-coercion refusal in Python 2.  I suspect this was motivated by a [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556839/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-unicode-work-in-python) where the asker seems to have gotten himself into trouble in ways it'd be harder to do in 3.

Comment: Nice question. I think this should have been worth a Python 2.x feature, would any still be added to that branch. - a command line switch to raise errors on mixing both types.

Comment: Especially since it's so important for transitioning to python 3, and that's kinda the point of the python 2.7 branch. At the very least, the unicode-nazi tool should get more publicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little more research after asking this question and hit on the perfect answer. Armin Ronacher created a wonderful little tool called [unicode-nazi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicode-nazi). Just install it and run your program like this:

```
python -Werror -municodenazi myprog.py
```

and you get a traceback right where the coercion happened:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "SITE-PACKAGES/unicodenazi.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File "SITE-PACKAGES/unicodenazi.py", line 119, in main
    execfile(sys.argv[0], main_mod.__dict__)
  File "myprog.py", line 4, in <module>
    print foo()
  File "myprog.py", line 2, in foo
    return 'bar' + u'baz'
  File "SITE-PACKAGES/unicodenazi.py", line 34, in warning_decode
    stacklevel=2)
UnicodeWarning: Implicit conversion of str to unicode
```

---

If you're dealing with python libraries that trigger implicit coercions themselves and you can't catch the exceptions or otherwise work around them, you can leave out the `-Werror`:

```
python -municodenazi myprog.py
```

and at least see a warning printed out on stderr when it happens:

```
/SITE-PACKAGES/unicodenazi.py:119: UnicodeWarning: Implicit conversion of str to unicode
  execfile(sys.argv[0], main_mod.__dict__)
barbaz
```

Answer (score 0):

That error isn't cryptic at all. I can gather from it that `urllib.quote()` (with is called by `quote_plus()`) doesn't handle unicode very well. Some quick googling and I've found [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557849/is-there-a-unicode-ready-substitute-i-can-use-for-urllib-quote-and-urllib-unquot) asking for unicode safe alternatives. Unfortunately, none seem to exist.